# Validation on extended fields UserDefinedForm

Tags: silverstripe

I have made an extension on the `UserDefinedForm` (module userforms). This works well, but I cannot figure out how to set validation on this extra fields. This is (a part of) my code:

```
class UserDefinedPaymentForm_Controller extends UserDefinedForm_Controller {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        "finished",
        "complete",
        "error"
    );

    public function getFormFields() {
        //Payment fields
        $supported_methods = PaymentProcessor::get_supported_methods();

        $gateways = array();
        foreach ($supported_methods as $methodName) {
            $methodConfig = PaymentFactory::get_factory_config($methodName);
            $gateways[$methodName] = $methodConfig['title'];
        }


        $fields = parent::getFormFields();

        $fields->add(new NumericField("PaymentAmount", _t('UserDefinedPaymentForm.PAYMENT_AMOUNT', 'Payment Amount')));
        $fields->add(new Literalfield("literalfield", _t('UserDefinedPaymentForm.PAY', '<h2>Pay</h2>')));
        $fields->add(new Literalfield("literalfield", _t('UserDefinedPaymentForm.PAY_INSTRUCTIONS', '<p>Choose your prefered payment method and click Pay:</p>')));
        $fields->add(new DropdownField("PaymentMethod", _t('UserDefinedPaymentForm.PAYMENT_METHOD', 'Payment Method'), $gateways));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Now I want to validate the field `PaymentAmount`, the value of this field has to be 2 or more. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess (I haven't tested this) your best bet is to create a subclass of `UserFormValidator` and override the `php($data)` method.
Then, in your UserDefinedPaymentForm_Controller, you will also need to override the `Form` method.

```php
class PaymentAmountUserFormValidator extends UserFormValidator {

    public function php($data) {
        $result = parent::php($data);
        if ($result === true) {
             // verify your PaymentAmount here and return true or false, accordingly
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

```php
class UserDefinedPaymentForm_Controller {
 ... 
    public function Form()
    {
        $form = UserForm::create($this);

        // Generate required field validator
        $requiredNames = $this
            ->getController()
            ->Fields()
            ->filter('Required', true)
            ->column('Name');

        $validator = new PaymentAmountUserFormValidator($requiredNames);
        $form->setValidator($validator);
        $this->generateConditionalJavascript();
        return $form;
    }

...

}
```